# Get footer at bottom of div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a div that I would like to put a fixed position footer on. It's very simple and light. When I add the `bottom: 0px; position: fixed;` to keep it at the bottom of the div, it goes to the bottom of the page and it's not even fixed. I'm usually pretty good with this stuff, but this has just driven me crazy. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/v5nw0daq/1/) is a link to a JSFiddle with the code. Please tell me what you think is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position fixed is relative to the whole document. Set the parent relative and the footer absolute:

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/aminmeyghani/wq21agqj/1/)

```
.post-contain { position: relative; }
.author-box {   position: absolute; }
```

Also why are you setting the p in the footer relative? See the updated demo.

Comment: I can't believe it was so simple

Comment: I will. I just can't quite yet. Won't let me for a few more minutes

Comment: I also updated the demo. I cleaned up the footer. Let the content of the footer set the height instead of setting a fixed value on the height.

Comment: This is going to sound really weird, but I think you're the nicest person to ever answer one of my questions on here. Usually people are reluctant to even answer.

Answer (score 0):

position: fixed is relative to the page.

What you really want is to set
.post-contain { position: relative }
.author-box { position: absolute }